# Gray-scale lighting from world, color lighting from fire

Tags: lighting

I have a project I am working on, it's a short animation about someone who is suffering from shock after witnessing their village being slaughtered. And I thought that it would be a really interesting aesthetic if everything being lit from natural lighting (not including fire) was on the gray-scale, and the only time there is ever any color is when fire is lighting it. The reason being I want to add a feel of numbness to show how he feels, that everything is numb and the only time he feels anything is when he's looking into the fire remembering what happened.

Comment: Have you achieved this effect yet?   Blender can do this using a fairly basic technique, or perhaps with nodes also.  The basic method would be to separate those objects to be unaffected by the firelight into another layer.  Set the lighting in each as required and in all levels, set lights to  "This Layer Only".

Comment: I have not. And that's not exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. I want the fire to saturate textures. Im not sure if that's possible though.

Comment: I'm sure it would be possible and if all items were to be saturated this way, the question arises - use each item's texture/colours or just the one, e.g. the fire's colour?  The material slot(s) for each could have their fallback colour set or keyframed to whatever, and the "color" setting in the textures properties wound back so the items get a matte effect flickering perhaps and in synch with the fire.